# The GetBytes function can only be used on columns of type Text, NText, or Image but not for nvarchar datatype

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, ado.net

```
byte[] outbyte = new byte[dr.GetBytes(dr.Getordinal["Notes"], 0, null, 0, 0)];
long y = dr.GetBytes(dr.Getordinal["Notes"], 0, outbyte, 0, 1000);
encodedtext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outbyte);
```

exception i got is The GetBytes function can only be used on columns of type Text, NText, or Image but not for nvarchar datatype.

```
Note: Here "Notes" column is a nvarchar type.
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS product which are you using (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server ... etc.). "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product

Comment: Yes , As you told i tagged the related links

Comment: I think the error message is reasonably clear - you don't use `GetBytes` for this column. You don't have to jump through hoops. Just call `GetString()` on the relevant column in the reader.